# How to append HTTP headers and append query parameters in one request using declarativeNetRequest rules?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

With Manifest V2, it is possible to have access to the sequence of events in webRequest API.

I can easily block requests, modify headers, append additional query parameters and then redirect to constructed URL.

The outcome is that there is one request that is redirected to the newly constructed URL, which has **all** modifications (including modified headers and new query parameters).

Now, I'm trying to do the same in Manifest V3 using [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) API. I cannot find any official docs on how could I have the same functionality in MV3.

I have defined two [dynamic rules](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#method-updateDynamicRules):

```js
addParameterToRequest: {
  addRules: [
    {
      id: 1,
      priority: 1,
      action: {
        type: 'redirect',
        redirect: {
          transform: {
            queryTransform: {
              addOrReplaceParams: [{key: data.key, value: data.value}],
            },
          },
        },
      },
      condition: {
        urlFilter: data.urlPattern,
        resourceTypes: ['main_frame'],
      },
    },
  ],
  removeRuleIds: [1],
},
addCookie: {
  addRules: [
    {
      id: 3,
      priority: 1,
      action: {
      type: 'modifyHeaders',
        responseHeaders: [
          {header: 'Cookie', operation: 'append', value: data.value},
        ],
       },
       condition: {
         urlFilter: data.urlPattern,
         resourceTypes: ['main_frame'],
       },
     },
   ]
   removeRuleIds: [3],
}
```

In MV3, the outcome is that I have two requests - one which was redirected with an appended query parameter, and the second one with a modified header.

**Manifest V2** results:

- Original URL = `https://localhost/route`
- Modified URL = redirected `https://localhost/route?qparam=value` with appended value in `Cookie` header

**Manifest V3** results:

- Original URL = `https://localhost/route`
- Modified URL #1 = redirected `https://localhost/route?qparam=value`
- Modified URL #2 = `https://localhost/route` with appended value in `Cookie` header

I tried to somehow combine these two rules into one, but with no success. I tried to play with `priority` in these rules, but whatever I do, the outcome is that I always have two requests instead of one.

How can I achieve the same functionality in MV3?

Comment: There's no way to combine rules. I guess you should use a different priority or specify the new URL's parameter in your addCookie `urlFilter` e.g. data.urlPattern + '*' + encodeURIComponent(data.key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data.value). If it doesn't work, open a feature request on https://crbug.com to allow specifying multiple actions in one rule.

Comment: @wOxxOm Changing priority doesn't help here, as I still make two requests to the endpoint instead of one. This is something that I want to avoid, because when these data are being processed, I get one request without cookie and second request without query parameters.

I tried to follow your suggestion, but I get 'Provisional headers' warning, which is concerning. I also tried to mix webRequest to append Cookie header and then redirect with declarativeNetRequest, but the outcome is still the same - two requests instead of one.

Comment: I see. Arguably the only solution will be to implement `actions` field which is an array of `action` type.